# Inner join with three table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my database: comment, landmarks, user and I want to get some attributes from each table, I try with below query but there's nothing retrived, this are my 3 tables

```
user (userid,firstName,lastName)
comment (userid,L_ID,review)
landmarks (L_ID,Title)
```

user and comment on userid
and comment with landmarks on L_ID

```
  $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT l.*,c.id,c.review,CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) name FROM landmarks l inner join comment c on l.L_ID on c.L_ID inner join users u on u.userid=c.userid WHERE ".(isset($userid) ? "c.userid=$userid" : (isset($landmarkid) ? "c.L_ID=$landmarkid" : "") )." ORDER BY c.id");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an error in the ON part of your "inner join comment c"

```
SELECT l.*,c.id,c.review,CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) name 
FROM landmarks l 
inner join comment c 
    on l.L_ID 
    on c.L_ID 
inner join users u 
    on u.userid=c.userid 
WHERE ".(isset($userid) ? "c.userid=$userid" : (isset($landmarkid) ? "c.L_ID=$landmarkid" : "") )." 
ORDER BY c.id
```

I believe what you want is

```
SELECT l.*,c.id,c.review,CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) name 
FROM landmarks l 
inner join comment c 
    on c.L_ID = l.L_ID 
inner join users u 
    on u.userid=c.userid 
WHERE ".(isset($userid) ? "c.userid=$userid" : (isset($landmarkid) ? "c.L_ID=$landmarkid" : "") )." 
ORDER BY c.id
```

Comment: Not a problem, we all do it.. don't forget to select answer if this was your fix.